# how to stop a android service at boot completed from writing data in to sdcard ,before sdcard prepared?

Tags: android, service

I have a peculiar problem , i have an android service which starts on boot complete.
service does the work of reading file from sdcard and writing pid to sdcard but .
using logs i came to know that the reason is :unable to write dat in to sdcard
permission denied ..
after some time the service restarts and writes data in to sdcard..
problem here is my service starts writing data even before the sdcard is prepared..
and write as soon as it is prepared .
Is there any way to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if [Environment.getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29)

This returns the state of the SDCard. You can call StopSelf() of the service to stop it.